# Java modulus left hand operand smaller than right hand operand

Tags: java, modulus

How java calculate remainder if left operand is smaller than left operand?

```
public class ModulusTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a = 3 , b = 10;

        int modul1 = b%a;
        System.out.println("b modulus a = " + modul1);

        int modul2 = a%b;
        System.out.println("a modulus b = " + modul2);

    }
}
```

Output:

```
b modulus a = 1
a modulus b = 3
```

Looks like it returns only left operand?

Comment: What are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If left operator is lesser than the right operand in the `mod(remainder)` operation,Java language specifies that the result will always be the left-hand smaller operand.

Hence,

```
3%10=3
```

in Java...

**So,YOU CAN'T GO AGAINST LANGUAGE SPECIFICATIONS!!!**

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "left operand"?

The modulo of `3/10` is `3` that is

```
0*10 + 3
```

while the modulo of `10/3` is `1` that is

```
3*3 + 1
```

What's the problem?